# Sources in Born-Infeld Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism

What are the ways that charge/current densities are incorporated into the Born-Infeld Lagrangian?

In the paper [Point Charge in the Born-Infeld Electrodynamics](https://cds.cern.ch/record/341074/files/9712161.pdf) it appears that 4-current is incorporated by simple addition (though it's not explicitly given there):

$$L = -b^2 \sqrt {1-\frac {(E^2-B^2)}{b^2} - \frac {(\vec E \cdot \vec B)^2}{b^4} } +b^2 + j^{\mu} A_\mu.$$

However, it seems to me that it would make a bit more sense to incorporate it this way:

$$L = -b^2 \sqrt {1-\frac {(E^2-B^2)}{b^2} - \frac {(\vec E \cdot \vec B)^2}{b^4} + j^{\mu} A_\mu} +b^2 .$$

Has this  alternative been explored, and are there other alternatives that have been explored?

Comment: *What are the ways that charge/current densities are incorporated into the Born-Infeld Lagrangian?* If you don’t incorporate it in the way that Born and Infeld did, then it isn’t the Born-Infeld Lagrangian but some variant.

Comment: I have a feeling that your variant might screw up the Lorentz force law even for weak fields. Born and Infeld’s idea was to introduce nonlinearities in the field that matter only for strong fields.

Comment: At first glance it seems that it wouldn't screw up the Lorentz force law because I think the first-order terms in the binomial expansion of the Lagrangian would be the same in both variants.

Comment: That seems plausible.

Comment: You added the square in the first equation but not the second.

Comment: I think I got it right this time!  Do you know of other variations?  I do think it's incomplete: it ignores any kinetic energy that the current might have.

Comment: No, sorry, I don’t know what variants have been considered or are viable.

Comment: Isn't the point that the first Lagrangian is gauge invariant, while the second one isn't. That is to say, to get a total divergence of the current (after a gauge tf) you'd need to perform a integration by parts, which would produce additional terms for the second Lagrangian

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your point.  Additional terms are expected to be produced, of course, just as the B-I Lagrangian produces terms that are not present in the usual Lagrangian for electrodynamics.

Comment: Well if you expand the square roots you'd get a plethora of terms. In the first Lagrangian every single one of those terms are gauge invariant by themselves. Yet if you'd expand the second Lagrangian there will be cross terms with the current. During a gauge transformation, the gauge field gives a piece proportional to the derivative of an arbitrary function. This derivative can be moved by an integration by parts, and the terms where the derivative acts on the current vanish since it's conserved. But I would expect  tons of other non-vanishing terms from the integration by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the theory has point-like sources then inclusion of a current under the square root is problematic. The current field of a point charge $q$ has a delta-like singularity:
$$
j^0(t,\mathbf{x}) = q \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_q(t)),\qquad \mathbf{j}(t,\mathbf{x}) = q\, \mathbf{v}_q(t) \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_q(t)).
$$
If the coupling term $j^\mu A_\mu$ enters the Lagrangian linearly, then its integration over spacetime would produce a well-defined quantity. However if we insert this term inside a nonlinear function like a square root then the result would be undefined: Taylor expansion of the square root would contain powers of delta-functions.

If the theory only has charged *fields* rather than point charges then it is indeed possible to include coupling term under the square root but only in combination that ensure the gauge invariance of the dynamics. For example, for complex scalar field $\Phi$ one such combination would be $(D_\mu \Phi) (D^\mu \Phi)^\dagger$, where the covariant derivative is defined by $D_\mu\equiv \partial _\mu -i q A_\mu$. This expression also contains the kinetic term for the scalar field. Whether to include any additional terms under the square root depends on the origin of the theory and goals one tries to accomplish with it.

Today, the relevance of Born–Infeld theory largely comes from string theory where it arises as low energy effective action of D-branes, and so string theory offers heuristics about how one can incorporate specific features for Born–Infeld-like field theories. For more information on Born–Infeld action in string theory I would recommend reviews by [Tseytlin](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9908105) and by [Schwarz](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0103165).

---

For example, Dirac–Born–Infeld action of D$p$-brane ($p$ is a number of brane's spatial dimensions) in a static gauge is
$$S_\text{DBI}=T_p\int d^{p+1}σ\sqrt{−\mathop{\rm det}(η_{αβ}+∂_αX^i∂_βX_i+ 2πα^′F_{αβ}) }.$$
Here $T_p$ is a brane tension, $X^i$ are transverse coordinates and a critical field strength of the Maxwell field is inversely proporional to string constant $α^′$. The $\mathop{\rm det}(η + F)$ structure is a generalization of expression under square root valid for arbitrary dimensions. When $p=3$ and $X\equiv 0$ one recovers an ordinary Born–Infeld Lagrangian.

From the worldvolume point of view  $X$'s are scalars, and they do not carry a charge. But one can consider a non-Abelian generalization of DBI action where both $F$-field and $X$ coordinates become non-Abelian/matrix-valued. In string theory such enhancement occurs for a stack of several coinciding D-branes. If this enhanced gauge symmetry is subsequently broken then, depending on the details, we could end up with a field theory containing at low energies an (Abelian) Maxwell field and one or several complex scalars now carrying charges with the action of the form
$$
S=T_p\int d^{p+1}σ\sqrt{−\mathop{\rm det}(η_{αβ}+(D_α\Phi) (D_β\Phi)^\dagger+ b^{-1} \, F_{αβ}) }+V(|\Phi|)+…,
$$
where $V$ is the potential (possibly with mass term) for the scalar field and by dots we denote all the terms irrelevant to the dynamics of scalar and Maxwell fields. The lowest order terms of Taylor expansion for this action near $\Phi=0$ and $F=0$ would give an ordinary scalar electrodynamics.

Comment: I don't have the proper background to follow some parts of your answer (yet).  However, I think the gist of your third paragraph is that it *might* be okay to put the $j^\mu A_\mu$ under the square root, depending on gauge invariance and the goal of the effort.  My hope is to find ways to replace $j^\nu$ with a function of the EM 4-potential in such a way that stationary particle-like solutions can exist.  Just replacing $j^\nu$ with $(\frac {1}{\mu_0}) \partial _\mu F^{\mu \nu}$ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you are introducing derivatives of Faraday tensor into Lagrangian, then the order of E–L equations (likely) would increase. You need additional degrees of freedom (fields), not necessarily carrying U(1) charges, See e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0007228) for example of regular particle like solutions in EBI-dilaton-axion theory.

Comment: Also, have a look at a no-go theorem for regular particle-like solutions of nonlinear electrodynamics at [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(79)90235-5).